# Intermediate value problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ continuous such that $x-1\leq f(x)\leq x+1$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Show that for any real $y$ there exist $c\in \Bbb R$ with $f(c)=y$.

Can I take a function $g(x)=f(x)-y$ for any $y$?

I need precise way of writing.

Comment: What is $y$? Is it a given number?

Comment: See my recent edits.

Comment: Yes. It is. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the abscissa $(y-1)$, we have $f(x)\leq x+1=y$. At the abscissa $(y+1)$, we have $f(x)\geq x-1=y$. Since $f$ is continuous over all real numbers, intermediate value theorem can be applied over the interval $[y-1,y+1]$ to show the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$. The inequality $f(x) \leqslant x+1$ tells you that $f$ is as small as you want, so you can find $a$ such that $f(a) \leqslant y$ (take $a=y-1$ for example).

In the same way, $x-1 \leqslant f(x)$ tells you $f$ can be as big as you want, so you can find $b$ such that $f(b) \geqslant y$.

Now, you know that $f([a,b])$ is an interval by the intermediate value theorem ! And it contains $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, so it must contain $y \in [f(a), f(b)]$. Hence you know that $y \in f([a,b])$.

Comment: Nice answer +1. Thank you!